# How do I compile the rust GTK example to the gtk crate? "#[doc(alias)] is experimental"

Tags: rust, gtk

I have been trying to learn the Rust language. I have managed to create some simple command line applications but now I am moving on to see if I can create an application that uses a graphical interface. I have looked into several GUI libraries including iced and the Qt API, but they have not worked out. I have most recently landed on GTK. I grabbed the example from the gtk crate documentation at

https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/

There is no information on that page on what to put into the Cargo.toml file so I have been trying to figure it out. The answers I have found on the web so far have been no help at all. So I went to crates.io and grabbed the the latest version of the gtk crate, 0.14.3, and put that into the toml.

```toml
[package]
name = "gtkhello"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["brian"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
gtk = "0.14.3"
```

Here is the example program, copied unaltered from the documentation.

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        // We create the main window.
        let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();

        // Don't forget to make all widgets visible.
        win.show_all();
    });

    app.run();
}
```

When I attempt to build this with cargo the compilation of the library fails. I do not know how to continue if the library itself will not compile. Here are the errors:

```
[brian@localhost gtkhello]$ cargo build
   Compiling glib-macros v0.14.1
   Compiling gdk-pixbuf-sys v0.14.0
error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:202:1
    |
202 | #[doc(alias = "get_full_ident")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:248:1
    |
248 | #[doc(alias = "get_keyword")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:366:1
    |
366 | #[doc(alias = "get_expr")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:413:1
    |
413 | #[doc(alias = "get_return_kind")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:474:5
    |
474 |     #[doc(alias = "get_closure")]
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

error[E0658]: `#[doc(alias)]` is experimental
   --> /home/brian/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/glib-macros-0.14.1/src/clone.rs:579:1
    |
579 | #[doc(alias = "get_closure")]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: see issue #50146 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146> for more information

   Compiling gdk-sys v0.14.0
error: aborting due to 6 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `glib-macros`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

I went to the link that was suggested in the error messages for the [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/50146) and it ends with:

> bors closed this in 57c5f40 on Sep 14, 2020

So I guess my question has several facets. What do I put into the Cargo.toml file to make this example work? How do I find that information in the future should I branch out from this simple example? How do I get around a required crate that will not compile? How do I tell cargo that experimental code is OK by me?

The biggest question is "What am I missing?"

Comment: What's your Rust version? Looks like it's too old and therefore unsupported by gtk-rs.

Comment: $ rustc --version
rustc 1.43.1

Answer (score 2):

The referenced feature was previously unstable, but stabilized [in version 1.48.0](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#version-1480-2020-11-19). So, minimal supported Rust version for `gtk-rs` is at least 1.48.0.

In general, if you see some crate failing to compile with reference to "unstable features", but the corresponding tracking issue is already closed, this usually means that your compiler version is older then the minimal supported by the crate in question. If the tracking issue is open, i.e. the feature is not stabilized yet, the crate might be nightly-only - in this case you have to add the necessary toolchain with `rustup install nightly` and then either set is as global default via `rustup default nightly`, or set an [override](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) (the easiest way is with `rustup override nightly`) for current project only.

Comment: Thanks for that information. I will look into upgrading my compiler. I am running linux and installed rust from the repositories, so I will have to do some research to figure out how to upgrade.

Comment: It's recommended to use Rustup - https://rustup.rs/ - instead. Versions in the system repositories can be quite old, depending on the maintainers.

Comment: I uninstalled the repository version of rust and reinstalled using rustup. My rustc version is now 1.57.0. The example compiles cleanly and works fine. Thanks for the help.